# Pérdida de evento luego de usar load() de jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy teniendo problemas con jquery,  estoy refrescando un div de mi página con load así:

```
$("#tablaArticulos").load(" #tablaArticulos");.
```

Dentro de esa caja lo que se refresca es una tabla con registros y un botón de submit asignado a cada registro, el problema es que al hacer load el submit no me funciona, ni siquiera envía.

Fuera de esa tabla también estoy refrescando otro div que tiene otro formulario, en este caso sí hace submit pero no envía los dato. Alguno me podría ayudar a resolver el problema, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué refrescas los divs en vez de agregarles el contenido o cambiarlo? ¿Cuál es el código que usas? ¿Qué significa esto: `$("#tablaArticulos").load(" #tablaArticulos")`?

Comment: Yo envío datos a la base de datos con ajax, una vez agregados utilizo  $("#tablaArticulos").load(" #tablaArticulos") para recargar el div que tiene la tabla con los registros.
Cada vez que yo agregue un registro yo actualizo esa tabla para mostrar los datos recién agregado, pero solo ese tag no la página. Pero como indicaba, el submit me deja de funcionar.